# Document.getElementsByTagName("span") problem with power shell version 2 windows 7

Tags: powershell

i,m write a a powershell script to open a web page by internet explorer and check the web page to find a link on the webpage by span tag and click on link to open a link but $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word" not working in windows 7 powershell version 2 , script is :

```
    $IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://device.com/link.html")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$go = $stream.ReadToEnd() 
$IE.navigate($go)
$IE.visible=$true
start-sleep 10
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://device.com/word.html")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$word = $stream.ReadToEnd()
write-host $word
$Link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word"}
$Link.click()
```

i want to replace any command to working this script with powershell version 2 in windows 7 and i don,t know what,s command can do that and find My mind link and click on that link with this script !

Comment: PowerShell 2 is deprecated, why do want to use it?

Comment: A number of active systems in our suite are using Windows 7 with powershell version 2  and can not be changed !

Comment: `$Link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word"}` could still return a collection of elements, not just one. Better change that to `$Link = @($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word"})[0]`. Then check what you have received. Is that a link?

Comment: @Theo i Tested And Answer is post on last reply

Comment: @Theo  i Tested And Answer is post on last reply .

Answer (score 0):

Hello My Friend @Theo

Script Change To This :

```
$IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://device.com/link.html")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$go = $stream.ReadToEnd() 
$IE.navigate($go)
$IE.visible=$true
start-sleep 10
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://device.com/word.html")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$word = $stream.ReadToEnd()
write-host $word
$Link = @($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word"})[0]
$Link.click()
```

Not Working And Answer Is :

```
Cannot find an overload for "getElementsByTagName" and the argument count: "1".
At line:16 char:44
+ $Link = @($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("span") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -eq "$word"})[0]
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:17 char:12
+ $Link.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: If IE is in [protected mode](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-disable-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-2624507), then after `.Navigate()` the object is lost.. Check if `$IE` is not $null and also check `$IE.Document`. You can test if IE is in `protected mode` using this code: `$ieProtectedMode = ((Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3' -Name '2500').2500 -ne 3)`. Hope that helps.